# How to set Id attribute of TDs while adding row in DataTable using row.add(data).draw().node();

Tags: api, datatables, row

How do I set the "id" attribute of one TD when I add a new row using this [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add%28%29#Examples) of Datatables? Consider I have only one TD.

Comment: It doesn't makes to assign same `id` attribute to all `td` elements, can you please clarify what you need?

Comment: Just modified the question. If I can add Id for one TD, I can generate unique ID for other TDs by prefixing character with my iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from the API that performs an operation on newly added rows.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
    .rows.add( [
        new Pupil( 43 ),
        new Pupil( 67 ),
        new Pupil( 102 )
    ] )
    .draw()
    .nodes()
    .to$()
    .addClass( 'new' );
```

`.addClass()` is a jquery method that they use here to add `class="new"` to the newly added rows.

So, instead of adding a class to the row, you could find all `<td>` in that row using `.find()`, then use `.each()` to call a function on each `<td>` to modify its id attribute using `.attr()`.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var count = 0;

table
    .rows.add( [
        new Pupil( 43 ),
        new Pupil( 67 ),
        new Pupil( 102 )
    ] )
    .draw()
    .nodes()
    .to$()
    .find('td')
    .each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'td' + (count++)  );
    });
```

Notice the use of a `count` variable to ensure that each id assigned is unique.

Comment: Although this is a correct solution, it doesn't make sense to assign same `id` (for example `td0` to all `td` elements).

Comment: Oops, I was thinking that count would increment for each `<td>`. Need to use `.each()`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks  to AndrewMairose and Gyrocode.com. The solution is correct however I managed to get what I wanted by putting the text in <span> and assigning them ids. This way, I can address the content in the TD easily without requiring to assign IDs to TDs.

Comment: @FaisalKhan, consider accepting the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the count in the solution above, you can use the index created by jQuery-

```
.find('td')
    .each(function(**index**) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'td' + **index**  );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to let's say one of the column in td (say only 4th):

```
var datatableTable = $('#datatableTable').DataTable();
var json = JSON.parse(data);
for (var row in json) {
var toAdd = {
id: json[row].id,
name: json[row].name
};

var i = datatablePojectListTable.row.add(toAdd).draw().nodes().to$().find('td:eq(4)').each(function() {$(this).attr('id', 'td-' + idVal  );});
// Add ID to row
datatablePojectListTable.rows(i).nodes().to$().attr("id", idVal);
}
```