# Jquery DataTables - Change Data in Specific Cell Based on Row ID

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to change the 5th column's table data in my Jquery DataTable, by going to the specific table row ID.  By default, all of my table rows have an id of `row<id number>`.  For example:

```
<tr id="row147">
  <td>147</td>
  ...
```

To attempt to change a specific table data cell, I tried something like this

`table.row("#row" + data.job_id).data(variable).draw()`

But this writes data across the entire row in each table data cell.  How do I specify the table data cell within the row and just have it write in that with the DataTables API?

Comment: I tried `table.row(row).column(5).data(variable).draw()`, and while it isn't throwing any error, it is not updating the cell in that column.

Comment: disregard comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution by following this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552585/how-to-set-id-attribute-of-tds-while-adding-row-in-datatable-using-row-adddata).  Basically have to give every `<td>` an ID.  Then I can use `table.cell('#td_5_' + data.job_id).data(variable)` to write in the new data to a specific cell.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look something like this.  Add the initComplete:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uiDataTable").DataTable({
        "order": [[1, "asc"]],
        "pagingType": "full",
        "deferRender": true,
        "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
            $('tbody tr').each(function () {
                var nTds = $('td', this);
                var nTrs = $('tr', this);
                //row #  
                if (nTrs.context.id == "4") {
                    $(nTds[0]).text("Changing row 3 column 1");
                    //alert(sBrowser);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there no way to accomplish what I am asking via the API?  initComplete is an option..

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if you read through the docs on the [row-selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector)
you will notice it says:

> also optionally cells() and cell()) methods provide the ability to select rows from the table

So if you go to the [`cell` docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell()):

You will see the overloaded cell method:

```
cell( rowSelector, columnSelector, [ modifier ] )
```

For your case:

```
table.cell("#row" + data.job_id,'').data(variable).draw()

table.cell("#row" + data.job_id, column_index).data(variable).draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

[datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables)'s [cell](/questions/tagged/cell) method wont work when you change the order, because the rowIndex, is the order in which the row was loaded, not the order it is currently displayed like [here](http://live.datatables.net/poyoqoda/1/edit) . If you want it based on the current position in the table, it's probably easiest to use jQuery using row index -

```
$('#yourTableId tbody tr:eq(rowIndex) td:eq(columnIndex)').text('yourvalue');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var rowId = "row" + data.job_id;
var element = document.getElementById(rowId).cells;
element[index_of_column].innerHTML = "New content";`
```

Comment: I should have rephrased my question on how it is done via the DataTables API.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#'+table).find('tr#'+rowId).find('td:eq(colNum)').html(newValue);
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality because it lacks an explanation.  Expand upon your answer, so that it is not deleted.